# asp.net Web services issue

Tags: web-services

I have a webservice that returns a weather information to the client. When I run the webservices internally it runs perfectly fine.. But when client runs it, the client app hangs. On testing, I see that everything runs perfectly fine but by the end before sending response the processing just stops and never returns anything. So client app just hangs

Can anyone think what could possible would be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a small code sample would be more helpful...

Comment: Browser type?  Server technology?  Code?  You need way more details if anyone is going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are millions of possible issues. The only I can suggest is to check execution logs. Nevertheless, I cannot suggest exact location of logs until you specify platforms you use for web-services.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mike says it could be a million things.

However, if we look at what is the difference. There are 2 main things:

- On the local or remote network
- Logged in to local domain or not

My best guess is that there is a difference in authentication, when the call from the customer, comes through it gets treated as an anonymous user, and it hangs when then server tries to access a local resource as the anonymous user.

You therefore need to check your security settings in IIS and web.config. You also need to check your code for access to local resources, a database or temp file...

Comment: this question has been reframed and posted back.. as webservices never returned back